# Trying to create a Vlookup formula via VBA Code

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a code to use Vlookup formula through VBA but i am stuck that how to fix it. It is very simple to lookup a range but i do not know what to do. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Sub Example()

Dim value As Range
Dim table As Range
Dim col_index As Range
Dim FinalResult As Variant

lRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Set value = Sheet2.Range("A2")
Set table = Sheet1.Range("A2:D15")
Set col_index = Sheet2.Range("D2:D" & lRow)

FinalResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(value, table, col_index, False)

End Sub
```

Here is the formula which is working perfectly

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$15,4,FALSE)
```

Edited

```
Sub Example()
Dim value As Range
Dim table As Range
Dim col_index As Range
Dim FinalResult As Variant
lRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Set value = Sheet2.Range("A2")
Set table = Sheet1.Range("A2:D15")
FinalResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(value, table, 4, False)
End Sub
```

Edited but still not working

```
Sub Example()
Dim rng As Range
Dim table As Range
Dim col_index As Range
Dim FinalResult As Variant
lRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Sheet2.Range("A2")
Set table = Sheet1.Range("A2:D15")
FinalResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rng, table, 4, False)
rng.value = FinalResult.value
End Sub
```

Comment: column index is a number not a range.  I believe you want `4` and not `Sheet2.Range("D2:D" & lRow)`

Comment: Exactly @Scott Craner

Comment: But its still not working @Scott Craner after edited

Comment: Please show the edited code.

Comment: Sub Example()

Dim value As Range
Dim table As Range
Dim col_index As Range
Dim FinalResult As Variant

lRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Set value = Sheet2.Range("A2")
Set table = Sheet1.Range("A2:D15")


FinalResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(value, table, 4, False)

End Sub

Comment: [edit] the post do not use comments.

Comment: @Scott Craner i did it

Comment: What error do you get and on what line?

Comment: Nothing happens when run the code.

Comment: Please don't use `value` as a variable name. Use some other name, e.g `rng`. But... you don't do anything with `FinalResult`. What do you want to do with it?

Comment: Well you do nothing with FinalResult it is stored in memory till the sub ends then it is dropped.  You need to put the value somewhere.

Comment: I edited gain but its still not working can you please post an answer.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you have two tables.

1. Your data table in "`Sheet1`"

[image]

2. Your output table where you want the result ("`Sheet2`").

[image]

To get the countries from the data sheet ("`Sheet1`") you would use the formula (I use ";" as separator as I use nordic version of excel):

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$D$15,4,FALSE)
```

[image]

So in VBA this would look like this:

```
Sub Example()

Dim tbl As Range
Dim col_index As Range
Dim Lookup_val As Long 'if you use a numerical number as in my example
'Dim Lookup_val As String 'if you use a text or words + numbers as lookup criteria
Dim FinalResult As Variant 'I would consider to use string or long... more specific declaration if you know the datatype to be retrieved.

lRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row 'End row in the column we should WRTIE the answer from the vlookup function
EndRow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'End row of the range we would like to MATCH values
Set tbl = Sheet1.Range("A2:D15") 'Data table range

For i = 2 To EndRow 'What range we should loop through. We want to loop from row 2 until the last row in Column A for Sheet2
    Lookup_val = Sheet2.Cells(i, "A").value 'Value that should be use as lookup value in the "vlookup function"
    FinalResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Lookup_val, tbl, 4, False) 'Perform the vlookup function
    Sheet2.Cells(i, "B").value = FinalResult 'write the result of the vlookup finding
Next i 'check next row (go to next lookup value)
End Sub
```

---

If the vlookup function can't match a value in the table it will give you an error. I usually fix it dirty by wrapping the function in a error handling line and you need to *clear* the `FinalResult` value for each iteration, i.e.:

```
For i = 2 To EndRow
    FinalResult = "" 'To clear previous value from loop iteration
    Lookup_val = Sheet2.Cells(i, "A").value
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no value found
    FinalResult = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Lookup_val, tbl, 4, False)
    On Error GoTo 0 'continue loop anyway
    Sheet2.Cells(i, "B").value = FinalResult
Next i
```

---

Comment: Thank you, you’re amazing seriously incredible. Thank you so much i spent almost 2 hours consistent to find an way but finally you answered in great way. Thank you very very much for the help.

Comment: Thank you =), much appreciated! Glad the visual example can give you more context and put you in direction so you can accomplish the result you wish. Let me know if you have any other questions. Happy coding :)!

Comment: I understand completely as you described and i got my lacks as well. 
Thank you so much once again.

Comment: I got stuck sometimes too ^^ and it nice to have people around that will go the extra mile to explain :). Ofcourse! And thank you too! =).

Comment: Yeah you are right. But i always posted here to get help otherwise i often spend days to find the solution. I'm single person working on excel so that's why no one is around who could help else this forum. Thanks